# Cannot open COM using php

Tags: php, com

I am trying to read contents of word file. when i run this script on localhost i hear a beep and the page keeps loading and nothing happens. Do i need to make changes in php.ini or somewhere else to make COM work

> $word = new COM("word.application") or
>   die ("Could not initialise MS Word
>   object.");
>
> $word->Documents->Open(realpath("test.doc"));
>
> // Extract content.
>
> $content =(string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;
>
> echo $content;
>
> $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
>
> $word->Quit(); $word = null;
>   unset($word);

Answer (score 0):

> when i run this script on localhost i hear a beep

That's probably the `Word.Application` object encountering an error. Guess you should [stop doing what you're doing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) and try something else:

> ## Considerations for server-side Automation of Office
>
> ...
>
> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because **Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment**.

Comment: As to why it doesn't work, I'd hazard a guess that the user account PHP is running as does not have access to `test.doc`

Comment: test.doc is in the same dir and is accessible.  what i really have to do is strip the metadata (document title, subject, author, team, manager, company etc.) before attaching it and sending in mail. do u have suggessions how i can do this. with COM i would have used $word->ActiveDocument->BuiltInDocumentProperties but that isn't working